# Adding a column into pandas dataframe but on row by row basis

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I did not seem to find a question that exactly suits what I need.

I am iterative over a pandas dataframe row by row.
Then based on each item in the row I do some complex operations on some other set of dataframea nd files and do a regression. THe output of that regression, i would like to insert as a column into this original dataframe. Tried a few things, but its not working.

Here is what I am trying

```
import pandas as pd
...
dfd = <my dataframe>

dfd['new column'] = 0  #initializing with 0. THis also did not work

for i, row in dfd.iterrow():
    <do some complex operation>
    res = result of complex operation
    row['new column'] = res

print dfd.to_string()
```

At this point i still see all entired in new column as 0

Comment: When you loop over `dfd` with iterrow you're probably operating on a copy of the `dfd`, so assigning `row['new column']` to something assigns to the copy. Maybe you can come up with a simple reproducible example that demonstrates your problem so someone can help.

Answer (score 2):

To change the value of a col during row iteration, try this

```
df['new column'].iloc[i] = res
```

It might be cleaner to re-implement your function as follows

```
def complex_operation(row):
    ...
    return res

dfd['new column'] = dfd.apply(complex_operation, axis=1)
```